# How to embed components in one another in reactjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How do I import another component into this component?  Do I need to make another file and declare the class there?  If so, how would I import it into this scheme?  I am using `babel` and `webpack`.

Specifically, I want the input to be its own component and have its own state which is delivered into the `MyReactApplication` component.  I just need the input logic to be isolated because it will be used in many places within the app.

```
var React = require('react');
var ReactDOM = require('react-dom');

class MyReactApplication extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      color: "hotpink"
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({
      color: "steelblue"
    });
  }

  changeColor(event) {
    this.setState({
      color: event.target.value
    });
  }

  render() {
    const styleObj = {
      backgroundColor: this.state.color
    };

    return(
      <section className="temp" style={styleObj} id="my-user">
        <h1>{this.state.color}</h1>
        <input value={this.state.color} onChange={this.changeColor.bind(this)}  />
      </section>
    );

  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<MyReactApplication name="Mustafa"/>, document.getElementById("app"));
```

Comment: I think you already answered your question. Yes you need to create file and export/import it in usual way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

File number one :

```
import React from 'react';

export default class Textbox extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }
    render() {
        return (
          <span>my text box</span>
        )
    }
}
```

File number two will use the Textbox :

```
import React from 'react';
import Textbox from './textbox';

export default class Textbox extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }
    render() {
        return (
          <div className="texbox-wrapper">
              <Textbox />
          </div>
        )
    }
}
```

`babel` will transpile the files and `webpack` will see the dependencies and bundle the files together(with the right configuration).

Comment: Okay, sweet, this worked.  I replaced those two lines at the top (var React = ...) with the import statements.  I'm guessing the only difference between the way I had React importing before and now is ES5 vs ES6, right?

Comment: it's ES6 vs CommonJS style. both are fine if you are using webpack or nodejs to render on server side

Answer (score 1):

You have to import it: `import Component from './file'` or `var Component = require('./file');`

Then you might want to use it into your render `<Component />`

You should really have a look at the basics of React. https://facebook.github.io/react/tutorial/tutorial.html

Answer (score 1):

You need to make a new component out of the input file that you are trying to isolate and export it. Then you `import InputComponentName from 'file_path'` (es6) or `require('file_path')` (es5) and use it like `<InputComponentName />`.